# How to get MS-Access Database online and connect to it using Java?

Tags: java, ms-access, japplet

I am writing a game in Java, it is an applet. I want the user to create an account, and have it registered into a database. I know how to create a database on my computer, and do username and login checks, but how do I get the database online, so that users can login?

Comment: Why do you want to use MS-Access?

Comment: I'd use a web service, but that seems too simple.

Comment: You could use MySQL/PostgreSQL, which are often provided to you by your webhoster?

Comment: I am new to this idea of using a database online. I heard MS-Access was easy, but heckk. If they have a web service, that seems toooo simple. Tooo simple enough that I would use it. What web services are there?

Comment: Check out SimpleDb for an example: http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/

Comment: I would try steer clear of MS-Access in an online setting, I think even when you get it running it won't perform well handling multiple connections from different clients (applets in this case), as cularis said try mysql/postgres, you would just need to export your data from MS Access to it

Comment: @horst Is it free?

And eon Alright. So you are sure this works online?

Comment: Justin, there is a pricing info straight on the page I have linked. http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/pricing/ Btw, I have posted simpleDB as an example, you might find an alternative. No insult, but a minimum reading on what is sent as answer is required, there are also examples for games, which is pretty much your use case: http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/usecases_online_gaming/

Comment: Haha, sorry about that. It was still loading and wouldn't scroll down. Thanks for the links! I will probably go this method with simpleDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways, one is [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/). The examples are straight forward. An other way is to use an ODBC Jdbc [driver](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-09/03-qa-0922-access.html).

I am not really sure what the applet's restrictions do have for an impact, so check this in advance. If you just need a simple data repository, think about something like [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/), where you do not need an own server.

Comment: Well, I found a tutorial, it uses a driver. The driver connects to the MS-Access Database, but does that work online?

Comment: Depends pretty much on your scenario and where the database is located. As said above MS Access does not seem to be the best choice for that. Regarding the question, I would just try - it won't take long to write an example for this.